# Run "introduction_to_svm.cpp" from OpenCV 2.4.11 but got wrong support vectors

Tags: opencv, svm

I am new in using OpenCV, I run the "introduction_to_svm.cpp" sample code with Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7(64bit) PC, but could not get the right support vectors in the result image, the returned support vector is point(0,0), which is not the right answer. Have anyone ever encountered similar problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have received response from opencv's "questions", see http://code.opencv.org/issues/2978, thanks anyway.